# Laravel I created a namespace Admin in users controller but it says Class Admin does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create an admin panel in laravel, frontend will be an API. So I need to setup controllers on level laravelMain/admin

Now in order to do that I have created a controller which is http/controllers/Admin/UsersController

Now in UsersController when I try to create a namespace admin, the error on calling the controller says class admin does not exist. I am confused why it is looking for class admin, as its just a namespace following are codes of couple of files.

**web.php**

```
// Admin
Route::group( ['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::get(  '/login',  'UsersController@login' );
    Route::get(  '/register', 'UsersController@register' );
});
```

**Http/Controllers/Admin/UsersController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Traits\ApiResponse;

/**
 * Class UsersController
 *
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 */
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    use ApiResponse;

//    /**
//     * @var UsersRepository
//     */
//    private $repo;


    /**
     * UsersController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->repo = app( UsersRepository::class );
    }

    public function login()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        return view('register');
    }
}
```

Now when i try to call **laravelURL/admin/login** I get the error

```
ReflectionException (-1)
Class admin does not exist
```

[image: Error I am getting]

Now this error is due to namespace line in Users controller, which is strange. So need help to sort this out. There will be more controllers on same path with same namespace.

Comment: The error is not about the namespace. This error is about Laravel not being able to resolve the binding `admin` from ioc/the container. From what I see from your code this relates to the `middleware` called `admin`. Have you defined that middleware in the Kernel?

Comment: try running this command `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: @Luceos No, i am bit new to laravel, so how will I need to do that?

Comment: You either have to define a middleware group or route with the name `admin`. See: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php